Placement of ferrite choke in detector circuit
While reading through the RCA Receiving Tube manual, I came upon this circuit:

This is a tube-based grid-leak detector for a radio. Why is the RF choke placed in the signal path rather than 'isolating' the B+ supply like in the below diagram? From my understanding, a choke blocks AC while passing DC, meaning in Fig.27 no signal should appear at the output.

This schematic is my version, where choke FB1 is used to prevent an AC signal from shorting out the B+ supply and C7 restores the DC level of the applied signal to 0V. (Not shown on the schematic, left side is from the plate of the detector tube and right goes to an amplifier stage.)
Why is the choke in the first image placed in the signal path?

It's regrettable that so many sources use absolute, binary or compartmentalized language to explain continuous phenomena.
These statements have to be understood in context of a continuum variable; a choke "blocks AC", sure, but the immediate follow-up question implied is: how much?
Of course, they aren't very good at spelling out that implication, and so another victim has been claimed. Sorry, I guess. :-\
Or, another infamous curse that history has burdened us with: "current takes the path of least resistance." Oh, so I can put 1 and 1.01 ohm resistors in parallel, and ALL the current flows through the 1-ohm resistor?  But how does it even know..?  That would be wild -- and make for some interesting current control possibilities -- but no, that's absolutely just not how it works.  Current actually distributes according to the resistances of paths available.  Most of the current flows through the least resistance, but current is always shared, even when one branch has extremely high resistance (a 1Ω and 1GΩ resistor in parallel, with 1V applied, still flows 1A and 1nA respectively, and you can reproduce this measurement anywhere at any time).
Sadly, these errors are hardly unique, repeating across topics and through time.
How does one deal with this generally?
Well, for one, it will help to reflect upon the component and node equations.
Math itself -- maybe it's a drudgery, or annoying, or boring, or painful.  I don't know.  Students have all manner of reaction to the subject.  Some lucky students find that, going from a poor teacher to a good one, all it took is just someone a bit better interested in the subject, better at explaining it to others, showing how to find pleasure in solving the puzzles that mathematics shows us, both little and vast.
Whatever your experience with math, if you can embrace it, harness it, it can provide valuable insight here.  Just a simple observation will suffice.  Consider: the inductor is given as having impedance increasing proportional with frequency, and the capacitor, decreasing inversely.  Clearly neither of these quantities goes to zero or infinity at finite frequency.  So we can easily falsify an absolute statement.
About the circuit, what do they actually mean?
It's that we will have some amount of attenuation along the path, and depending on what values, and how many L and C, we use, that attenuation will vary with frequency, and can be tuned to mainly pass in one range, and mostly block (where "blocking" has been refined to "attenuation above the given threshold") in another.  That is, a low-pass or high-pass filter.  (Or, more specifically: a diplexing filter, so that DC/LF goes one way, and HF/RF goes the other, with the common (detector plate) sharing both.  Actually, kind of neither, but about that...)
Another quirk here, is the peculiar placement of the RFC.  There's probably two primary cases (and related/similar arrangements) that would apply here:

You can't exactly connect another vacuum tube across "AF OUTPUT" when one terminal of it is B+ itself; besides, we need to supply DC somehow, we certainly can't tie a grid in here all by itself.  Another decoupling network is needed, this time at AF.  We might use the RC coupling (top), or transformer coupling (bottom), or variants using (AF) chokes.
But here we find a problem: for the top case, the RF load is RL || RG, which will still be a very high impedance (100s kΩ).  To get any* reduction in RF due to the choke, its own impedance needs to be much higher than this resistance.  But good luck finding a 1MΩ RF choke anywhere!  (There are some frequency ranges where this is possible, but it's not exactly convenient to need such an inductor.)
*Aha, another absolutism!  Implied: "any meaningful"; more than a few dB attenuation, but preferably 20+ dB attenuation for, say, "a reasonable reduction".
The bottom one, the transformer's own leakage inductance contributes to (i.e. acts in series with) the RFC, but more comprehensively than that: a transformer is a band-pass type component, with some nominal impedance (Z1:Z2 as labeled) and which should be terminated into a matching impedance (RG).  It simply doesn't pass very much at frequencies outside the rated bandwidth (but, notice it's not a hard cutoff, and not even a gradual one: expect peaks and valleys in the upper cutoff band!).
We could also have a circuit like this,

where the detector is cascoded by another tube, the input (cathode) impedance of which is quite low (approx. 1/gm, typically under 1kΩ), so the RFC can now do an excellent job decoupling the detector plate (i.e., whatever RF voltage is left after the capacitor) from the subsequent circuit.
It's peculiar that RCA drew this diagram this way, but I think in context it's more of a throw-away example, and we're (read: me far more than you, lol) concentrating too hard on an irrelevant detail, when the point was just to show the grid detector scheme.

A final note, regarding your circuit: you show a "FB1 / 470u".  It's not clear what this means: "FB" is for "Ferrite Bead", consistent with the bead-like symbol, but "470u" might imply 470μH, quite a large inductance -- and nothing that's possible from a single pass through a small bead.  If this is a wound bead (perhaps you've passed many turns of fine wire through one yourself?), understand that it will saturate easily under DC bias -- perhaps even the small bias of a vacuum tube here.
A typical ferrite bead might be in the ballpark of 0.5μH/t2 at 1MHz, so 470μH needs 30t.  A typical bead-on-lead saturates in the range of 1At, or about 30mA here.  To be fair, that should still be safe for signal tubes running at a few mA; but you can see, it doesn't take much (lower saturation amp-turns, more turns, higher bias current) to put it over the limit.
What is saturation?  A saturated core offers much less impedance, so that your carefully-designed filter stops being carefully-designed past saturation (or, unless you've taken it into account, but then you'll need to measure how much saturation occurs in operation, and design around that).  Which, notice, isn't to say it'll stop working -- just that it won't work exactly as designed (i.e., impedance drops, cutoff frequency rises, attenuation falls).
Also, note all that wire will also have some capacitance to itself, reducing the frequency range where it's most suitable (highest impedance) at.  I don't have a strong feel for what 30+ turns would do on a small ferrite bead, but I would have to guess it puts the impedance peak somewhere in the 100s of kHz, maybe low MHz.  If you need to attenuate RF in the 10s or 100s of MHz, consider using a better-specified inductor, perhaps of smaller value, or using capacitors more prominently, or RC filtering, etc.

Back in the days of grid leak detectors, the "load" was often headphones. B+ on headphones, yikes. Radio was a bit of a reckless pursuit in the old days...

The RF choke in the RCA diagram removes the radio frequency components of the output signal from the detector.  It passes lower frequencies just fine - the recovered audio signal from the detector has no trouble passing through the choke.

A choke doesn't simply "pass DC while blocking AC."
The impedance of the choke varies with the frequency of the signal.  For very high frequency (radio frequency) signals on the order of 1 MHz or more, the impedance of the choke is very high - it acts like a high value resistor.  For lower frequencies, it presents a lower impedance.  At DC, it acts like a piece of wire.
You might want to take a look at the Wikipedia inductor page.
